# How install fpc-stl in freepascal on ubuntu

Tags: compiler

Please help me install fpc-stl (freepascal) on ubuntu.

[Standard Template Library (FCL-STL)]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? As far as I can tell, STL components have been incorporated into the generic `fp-units-fcl` package -
 see for example [File list of package fp-units-fcl-3.0.0 in xenial of architecture amd64](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/fp-units-fcl-3.0.0/filelist)

Comment: thanks for reply.
My ubuntu is 16.04

I known this package, but I don't know how to add this to my compiler (FreePascal 3.0.0).